# How to pass data to all views in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to have some default data accessible in all views in my Laravel 5 application.

I have tried to search for it but only find results for Laravel 4. I have read the documentation 'Sharing Data With All Views' [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/views) but I can't understand what to do. Where should the following code be placed?

```
View::share('data', [1, 2, 3]);
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: well, you need startup code to manage this requirement?

Comment: heads up using View::share in a service provider with the results of a database call will error out the application when running a refresh db migration or trying to run dusk with an unreachable db connection (long story, .env.dusk.local is used only after service provider is run). As mentioned below in a base controller or middlware is the best.

Comment: Also be careful when using `*` on view composers especially if using db queries, as it is run for every included sub view, component, etc, so you could end up running hundreds of unnecessary queries, best thing is to use the base view e.g. layouts.app then pass data down as needed.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

This target can achieve through different method,

**1. Using BaseController**

The way I like to set things up, I make a `BaseController` class that extends Laravel’s own `Controller`, and set up various global things there. All other controllers then extend from `BaseController` rather than Laravel’s Controller.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //its just a dummy data object.
    $user = User::all();

    // Sharing is caring
    View::share('user', $user);
  }
}
```

**2. Using Filter**

If you know for a fact that you want something set up for views on every request throughout the entire application, you can also do it via a filter that runs before the request — this is how I deal with the User object in Laravel.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
  // Set up global user object for views
  View::share('user', User::all());
});
```

**OR**

You can define your own filter

```
Route::filter('user-filter', function() {
    View::share('user', User::all());
});
```

and call it through simple filter calling.

**Update According to Version 5.***

**3. Using Middleware**

Using the `View::share` with `middleware`

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'SomeMiddleware'], function(){
  // routes
});



class SomeMiddleware {
  public function handle($request)
  {
    \View::share('user', auth()->user());
  }
}
```

**4. Using View Composer**

View Composer also help to bind specific data to view in different ways. You can directly bind variable to specific view or to all views. For Example you can create your own directory to store your view composer file according to requirement. and these view composer file through Service provide interact with view.

View composer method can use different way, First example can look alike:

You could create an `App\Http\ViewComposers` directory.

*Service Provider*

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        view()->composer("ViewName","App\Http\ViewComposers\TestViewComposer");
    }
}
```

After that, add this provider to config/app.php under "providers" section.

*TestViewComposer*

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class TestViewComposer {

    public function compose(View $view) {
        $view->with('ViewComposerTestVariable', "Calling with View Composer Provider");
    }
}
```

*ViewName.blade.php*

```
Here you are... {{$ViewComposerTestVariable}}
```

This method could help for only specific View. But if you want trigger ViewComposer to all views, we have to apply this single change to ServiceProvider.

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        view()->composer('*',"App\Http\ViewComposers\TestViewComposer");
    }
}
```

**Reference**

[Laravel Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers)

For Further Clarification [Laracast Episode](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25)

If still something unclear from my side, let me know.

Comment: Your example is missing the `register()` method - it's not optional

Comment: @jonathan  thanks to point it out, but example contains only those section need to take care of. perspective to sharing data with view.

Comment: where do you put the filter?

probably the most correct answer is now using middleware groups https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware#middleware-groups or global middleware

Comment: Filter no more part of the family as per 5.* laravel, but of course you can use middleware as well to share data with views. and middleware group is different thing perspective to sharing data with views.

Comment: This is not a good idea, View composers create the composer instance for each individual view it means if you run a 1000 times loop, 1000 composer instances would be created and, 1000 times the firing event is handled which is not something you want.

Comment: @RezaShadman I really dont understand whats points you want to raise. can you explain it in further depth?

Comment: @RezaShadman if you have any other way to share data with views without the problem you're sharing, please share with us.

Comment: @SafoorSafdar checkout my answer.

Comment: @SafoorSafdar for first solution, don't all other controllers have construct function?

Comment: @horse its depends, you can call `parent::__construct();` from extend class construct function.

Comment: @RezaShadman is correct! I learnt this the hard way. My application was running so slow until I installed the laravel-debugbar tool to investigate. Then I realized that all 8 queries where being executed about 15 time for a single page load. This is because the view composer will be called for each blade file that is included. That is if you are using the asterisk `*`. If you are not using the `*` then you should be fine.

Comment: @Safoor Safdar Thanks I liked base-controller concept. Nice and easy. I already used this kind of thing in CI.

Answer (score 75):

You can either create your own [service provider](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/providers) (`ViewServiceProvider` name is common) or you can use the existing `AppServiceProvider`.

In your selected provider, put your code in the boot method.

```
public function boot() {
    view()->share('data', [1, 2, 3]);
}
```

This will make a `$data` variable accessible in all your views.

*If you rather want to use the facade instead of the helper, change `view()->` to `View::` but don't forget to have `use View;` at the top of your file.*

Comment: Thanks, working great. Is the boot function meant for this kind of thing or do you recommend creating my own service provider?

Comment: If you only got one or two things to share putting it in `AppServiceProvider` is fine, but if you got something more than that you should consider creating a new provider.

Comment: It was working but I just see that its not working today! using `composer update` also not working. Actually its not firing the `boot()` at all. I need to share two variables.

Comment: Be aware that this will not work if you're fetching database records as this will get called before executing migrations. So you're basically trying to fetch database records before they exist. At least that seems to be the case for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with sharing a logged in user Auth::user(), Safoor's #1 answer, below this one, does :)

Comment: @lorey what if I'm getting some cached data from Redis?

Answer (score 19):

I found this to be the easiest one. Create a new provider and user the `'*'` wildcard to attach it to all views. Works in 5.3 as well :-)

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function ($view)
        {
            $user = request()->user();

            $view->with('user', $user);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Comment: Add this provider into array of providers in your config/app "App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,"

Answer (score 11):

The best way would be sharing the variable using `View::share('var', $value);`

**Problems with composing using `"*"`:**

Consider following approach:

```
<?php
// from AppServiceProvider::boot()
$viewFactory = $this->app->make(Factory::class);

$viewFacrory->compose('*', GlobalComposer::class);
```

From an example blade view:

```
  @for($i = 0; $i<1000; $i++)
    @include('some_partial_view_to_display_i', ['toDisplay' => $i])
  @endfor
```

What happens?

- The `GlobalComposer` class is instantiated *1000* times using
  `App::make`.
- The event `composing:some_partial_view_to_display_i` is    handled
  *1000* times.
- The `compose` function inside the `GlobalComposer` class is called 1000 times.

But the partial view `some_partial_view_to_display_i` has nothing to do with the variables composed by `GlobalComposer` but heavily increases render time.

**Best approach?**

Using `View::share` along a grouped middleware.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'WebMiddleware'], function(){
  // Web routes
});

Route::group(['prefix' => 'api'], function (){

});

class WebMiddleware {
  public function handle($request)
  {
    \View::share('user', auth()->user());
  }
}
```

**Update**

If you are using something that is computed over the middleware pipeline you can simply **listen** to the proper **event** or put the view share middleware at the last bottom of the pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

You have two options:

**1. Share via ‍`Boot` function in `App\Providers\AppServiceProvider`:**

```
public function boot()
{
  view()->share('key', 'value');
}
```

And access `$key` variable in any view file.

`Note`: Remember that you can't access current `Session`, `Auth`, `Route` data here. This option is good only if you want to share static data. Suppose you want to share some data based on the current user , route, or any custom session variable you won't be able to do with this.

**2. Use of a helper class:**

Create a helper class anywhere in your application and register it in Alias array in `app.php` file in `config` folder.

```
 'aliases' => [ 
   ...,
  'Helper' => App\HelperClass\Helper::class,
 ],
```

and create `Helper.php` in HelperClass folder within App folder:

```
namespace App\HelperClass;
    
class Helper
{
    public static function Sample()
    {
        //Your Code Here
    }
}
```

and access it anywhere like `Helper::Sample()`.

You will not be `restricted` here to use `Auth`, `Route`, `Session`, or any other classes.

Comment: both good but .. they run before laravel session .

Answer (score 4):

In the documentation:

> Typically, you would place calls to the share method within a service
>   provider's boot method. You are free to add them to the
>   AppServiceProvider or generate a separate service provider to house
>   them.

I'm agree with Marwelln, just put it in `AppServiceProvider` in the boot function:

```
public function boot() {
    View::share('youVarName', [1, 2, 3]);
}
```

I recommend use an specific name for the variable, to avoid confussions or mistakes with other no 'global' variables.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation is hear https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers but i will break it down

1. Look for the directory **app\Providers** in the root directory of your application and create the file **ComposerServiceProvider.php** and copy and past the text below into it and save it.

   ```
   <?php
       namespace App\Providers;
       use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
       use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

       class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
       {
           /**
           * Register bindings in the container.
           *
           * @return void
           */
       public function boot()
       {
           // Using class based composers...
           View::composer(
               'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
           );

           // Using Closure based composers...
           View::composer('dashboard', function ($view) {
               //
           });
       }

       /**
       * Register the service provider.
       *
       * @return void
       */
       public function register()
       {
           //
       }
   }
   ```
2. From the root of your application open **Config/app.php** and look for the Providers section in the file and copy and past this *'App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider',* to the array.

By doing this, we have created the Composer Service Provider. When you run your application with the view Profile like so *http://yourdomain/something/profile*, the service provider *ComposerServiceProvider* is called and the class App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer is instantiated calling the method Composer due to the code below inside the boot method or function.

```
 // Using class based composers...
 View::composer(
   'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
 );
```

3. If you refresh your application you will get an error because the class **App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer** does not exist yet. Now lets create it.

Go to the directory path app/Http

- Create the directory called ***ViewComposers***
- Create the file **ProfileComposer.php**.

  ```
  class ProfileComposer
  {
      /**
      * The user repository implementation.
      *
      * @var UserRepository
      */
      protected $users;

      /**
      * Create a new profile composer.
      *
      * @param  UserRepository  $users
      * @return void
      */
      public function __construct(UserRepository $users)
      {
          // Dependencies automatically resolved by service container...
          $this->users = $users;
      }

      /**
      * Bind data to the view.
      *
      * @param  View  $view
      * @return void
      */
      public function compose(View $view)
      {
          $view->with('count', $this->users->count());
      }
  }
  ```

Now go to your view or in this case Profile.blade.php and add

```
{{ $count }}
```

and that will show the count of users on the profile page.

To show the count on all pages change

```
// Using class based composers...
View::composer(
    'profile', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
);
```

To

```
// Using class based composers...
View::composer(
    '*', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\ProfileComposer'
);
```

Comment: <?php and namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View; is missing from ProfileComposer.php

Answer (score 2):

**1) In (app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php)**

```
// in boot function
       view()->composer('*', function ($view) {
            $data = User::messages();
            $view->with('var_messages',$data);
        });
```

**2) in Your User Model**

```
  public static function messages(){ // this is just example
        $my_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $data= Message::whereTo($my_id)->whereIs_read('0')->get(); 
        return $data; // return is required
    }
```

**3) in Your View**

```
 {{ $var_messages }}
```

Answer (score 2):

I created **ViewServiceProvider** for passing data for multiple views, in **Laravel 8**

1. Creating **app/Provides/ViewServiceProvider.php** file.

```
class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
   
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
   
    public function boot()
    {
        //for user views(resources/views/user/*)
        View::composer(['user.*'], function ($view) {
            $f_user = Auth::user();
            $f_platform = 'user';
            $view->with(compact( 'f_user', 'f_platform'));
        });

        // for admin views(resources/views/admin/*)
        View::composer('admin.*', function ($view) {
            $f_admin = Auth::guard('admin')->user();
            $f_platform = 'admin';
            $view->with(compact( 'f_admin', 'f_platform'));
        });

        //for all views(resources/views/*)
        View::composer('*', function ($view) {
            $f_something = [];
            $view->with(compact('f_something'));
        });

    }
}
```

2. Register **ViewServiceProvider** in **config/app.php**

```
  'providers' => [
        ...
        App\Providers\ViewServiceProvider::class,

    ],
```

3. Using in blades

```
{{ $f_user }}
{{ $f_platform }}
{{ $f_something }}
```

```
{{ $f_admin }}
{{ $f_platform }}
{{ $f_something }}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best way is with `View Composers`. If someone came here and want to find how can do it with View Composers way, read my answer => [How to share a variable across all views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040684/how-to-share-a-variable-across-all-views)

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#view-composers but i will break it down
1.Look for the directory Providers in your root directory and create the for ComposerServiceProvider.php with content

Answer (score 1):

Inside your config folder you can create a php file name it for example "variable.php" with content below:

```
<?php

  return [
    'versionNumber' => '122231',
  ];
```

Now inside all the views you can use it like

```
config('variable.versionNumber')
```

Comment: I do it this way in some cases, because the information is truly global and you can access it from anywhere. For that reason, I call the config file "global.php" and I put anything in there that I want to be accessible in all other portions of my code. Only limitation is that this is for static data, and gets cached. It shouldn't be used this way if you have constantly changing data.

Answer (score 1):

Laravel 5.6 method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#passing-data-to-views

Example, with sharing a model collection to all views (AppServiceProvider.php):

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use App\Product;

public function boot()
{
    $products = Product::all();
    View::share('products', $products);

}
```

Comment: This will cause issues if you are trying to create a fresh application with an empty database.

Answer (score 0):

for example you can return list of all tables in database to the all views of Controller
like this :

```
public function __construct()
{
    $tables = DB::select('SHOW TABLES'); // returns an array of stdObjects
    view()->share('tables', $tables);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> In Laravel 5 and above versions , you can edit boot function in
> AppServiceProvider.php to access variable in all views

```
public function boot()
{
    \View::composer('*', function($view){
        $view->with('key', 'value');
    });
}
```

"Key" represents the name of the variable which you want to set, so that you can use it later in any .blade.php file and "value" represents the value represented by the variable... For Example :

//setting user role to be accessed by all blade.php files

```
public function boot(){
//
View::composer('*', function($view){
view->with('role', Auth::user()->infouser->role);
 });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If are you using **Laravel 8** you can do this like that,

```
class Controller extends BaseController{
use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

public function __construct(){
    $categories = Category::where('show_menu', '=', 1)->where('status', '=', 'approved')->get();
    view()->share('categories', $categories);
}}
```

Comment: view()->share('categories', $categories);

Comment: I think requesting any resource in constructor is a bad idea. Constructors must be responsible only for creating new instance and any initializing operations.

Comment: ... and if you make ajax requests to controller every time it will get data from category table.