# How to share a variable across all views?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I want information about the system locale to be available in every view, so I could highlight whatever language is currently selected by a user. After some googling around, I've found the value-sharing issue addressed in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#sharing-data-with-all-views). However, after putting the code into `boot()` like this:

```
class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{
    public function boot(){
        view()->share('locale', \Lang::getLocale());
    }
}
```

the `$locale` variable, when accessed in views, always holds the *default* system locale, not the *currently* selected one. Why?

Comment: I don't know about Laravel, but why don't you store it in a session variable?

Comment: I want to stick to the Laravel best-practices as much as possible. I don't think that would be a Laravel-way of doing things. Also, the mechanism that I describe above is designed to address such very issues, hence there has to be some way to solve this problem 'in the right way'. Thanks for the idea anyway :)

Comment: Ah ok, it was just a suggestion :)

Comment: You are not showing how you set the locale. Agree that @panagiotis answer seems over engineered although still awesome (or poli kala) . Your solution should work though

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I usually use View Composers so it's more clear and readable.

For example If I want to share a variable with the main navbar to all of my views I follow the below rules:

### 1. Create new service provider

You can create a service provider with artisan cli:

`php artisan make:provider ViewComposerServiceProvider`

In the *ViewComposerServiceProvider* file create *composeNavigation* method in which has the blade template *main.nav-menu* that represents the navmenu with shared variables.

The *ViewComposerServiceProvider* looks like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->composeNavigation();
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }

    private function composeNavigation()
    {
        view()->composer('main.nav-menu', 'App\Http\ViewComposers\NavComposer');
    }
}
```

### 2. Create Composer

As you saw in the file above we have *App\Http\ViewComposers\NavComposer.php* so let's create that file. Create the folder *ViewComposers* in the *App\Http* and then inside create *NavComposer.php* file.

The *NavComposer.php* file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use App\Repositories\NavMenuRepository;
use Illuminate\View\View;

class NavComposer
{
    protected $menu;

    public function __construct(NavMenuRepository $menu)
    {
        $this->menu = $menu;
    }

    public function compose(View $view)
    {
        $thing= $this->menu->thing();
        $somethingElse = $this->menu->somethingElseForMyDatabase();

        $view->with(compact('thing', 'somethingElse'));
    }
}
```

### 3. Create repository

As you saw above in the *NavComposer.php* file we have repository. Usually, I create a repository in the *App* directory, so create *Repositories* directory in the *App* and then, create inside *NavMenuRepository.php* file.

This file is the heart of that design pattern. In that file we have to take the value of our variables that we want to share with all of our views.

Take a look at the file bellow:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

use App\Thing;
use DB;

class NavMenuRepository
{

    public function thing()
    {
        $getVarForShareWithAllViews = Thing::where('name','something')->firstOrFail();
        return $getVarForShareWithAllViews;
    }

    public function somethingElseForMyDatabase()
    {
        $getSomethingToMyViews = DB::table('table')->select('name', 'something')->get();

        return $getSomethingToMyViews;
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on pros/cons of this approach? Sorry for being a newbie, but It's not quite clear to me. Is it not an overkill to write so much code for my exact situation?

Comment: If your project it will be big it's better to follow this because it's help to make the code reusable and readable. It's up to you...

Comment: @Panagiotis I guess you just forgot to mention adding this provider into array of providers of your app `App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class,`

Answer (score 2):

For people with small project:

Firstly, The accepted answer is awesome!

For Laravel 5.2 users:

Just use the new blade directive `@inject` within your views like this

`@inject('shared','App\Utilities\SharedWithView')`

then you can use it:
`{{ $shared->functionName() }}`

And SharedWithView is a simple class like this one:

```php
namespace App\Utilities;

use App\Repositories\SomeRepositoryLikeArticlesRepository;

class SharedWithView {

    public function functionName() {
        $properNameHere = new SomeRepositoryLikeArticlesRepository();

        return $properNameHere->forEaxmpleGetMostViewedArticles( 10 );
    }

}
```

Comment: if you need another solution for older Laravel version, please say so under this comment :-) and I'll post