# Laravel : having the same element on each of my pages

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

On Laravel 5.2, I'm trying to put two menus (X latest contents, and the same for a specific user) on near every page.

The lazy way would be to generate those arrays in each of the controllers, but is there a way to generate it when the templating system needs them ?

For instance, my template could call something like `{{ $menu }}` and the menu would be generated only when this was present ?

Comment: If you want more help about that you can see my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040684/how-to-share-a-variable-across-all-views/35042335#35042335

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's very useful !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Laravel has a feature called [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers) ,which lets you do some actions when a template file is loaded.

you could set the `X latest contents` into a template file and then include it wherever you want to and use view composer to fetch the data.

Comment: Thanks ! That's exactly what I was looking for !