# Passing data to layout in Laravel 5.2 on each request

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hi I am building an application using laravel 5.2 I have a messaging system and I would like to populate some sections in my layout like 'Current Unread Messages Count' and a summary of the last 5 messages.

The way i was gonna go about it is to call a method get the data that I need and then pass the data to the layout and then render the view.

I understand this can be done with a view composer but I have no idea how. Any input would be greatly appreicated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel : having the same element on each of my pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35105578/laravel-having-the-same-element-on-each-of-my-pages)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do that with a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers)

Let's suppose you have a `my_menu.blade.php` view file and you want to pass some data to it. In a service provider's `boot` method do:

```
//every time the my_menu view is rendered, this callback will be called
View::composer('my_menu', function( $view )
{
    $data = //get your data here

    //pass the data to the view
    $view->with( 'data', $data );
} );
```

Now, everytime the `my_menu` view will be rendered, Laravel will call your callback, fetch the data and pass the data to the view. So, in your view file, you can access the data with `$data`

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What you said works I actually found a video on laracasts wich explains this very well and even shows you how you can make ServiceProviders to keep this as clean as possible :)

https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25