# view composer laravel 5.0

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am facing an error when sharing data with views:

```
ErrorException in d280994c1185d651d47347db1597d7ed line 67:
Undefined variable: QandA (View: E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\wifaq-atropos\resources\views\_partials\_footer.blade.php) (View: E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\wifaq-atropos\resources\views\_partials\_footer.blade.php)
```

This is my code for `class AppServiceProvider`:

```
public
function boot() {
  View::composer('_partials._footer', function($view) {
    $QandA = \DB::table('qa') - > take(3) - > orderBy('id', 'desc') - > get();
    $view - > with('QandA', $QandA);
  });
}
```

This is my_footer.blade.php file:

```
@foreach($QandA as $QandA)
<div class="post-item">
  <small>JANUARY 2, 2014 BY ADMIN</small>
  <h3><a href="blog-single-sidebar-left.html">{{ $QandA->q }}</a></h3>
</div>
@endforeach
```

How can I fix this error? Also, when I discuss conversation on laracast, the button always remains disabled. Why? [See in link](http://prntscr.com/9x2rvg)

Comment: I test it. There is no problem @JoeS  
$QandA as $QandA. Any other solution?

Comment: You can see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040684/how-to-share-a-variable-across-all-views/35042335#35042335 maybe will help you

Comment: @Panagiotis 7 let me try it

Comment: its not working, what's wrong in my code  
@Panagiotis