# Laravel 5.2 : How to get a variable in a subView of a parentView from another subView?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Below is my views and controllers i want $name variable to be accessible in navbar view which is included in master view. does anybody know a solution ?

**userController.php**

```
public function index($var){
    $u_array = $var;
    $name = $u_array->name;
    return view('index',compact(name));
}
```

**master.blade.php**

```
@include('navbar')
<section class="main-container">
    @yield('content')
</section>
```

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    <h2>{{$name}}</h2>
@endsection
```

**navbar.blade.php**

```
<h1>{{$name}}</h1>
```

Comment: Does {{name}} display anything where it is currently?

Comment: yes it is displaying name from database.

Comment: Deleted my answer as it was not helpful to you.

Comment: Maybe open <?php .. ?> in the nav and then make a call to the DB from there. Hope you figure it out

Comment: Are you attempting to get the authorized user's name?

Comment: I notice you have `{{ name }}` in `index`, but it should be `{{ $name }}`. Since `index.blade.php` extends `master.blade.php`, then anything in `index` is also available in `master`, so it should be working.

Comment: Typing error corrected

Comment: No, its some variable i need to get in navbar view

Comment: @davin i need via blade template engine not from php code as i said in question.

Comment: If `$name` is defined in the `userController.php` file, then what you have above should be working. I use this exact concept all over my applications. Perhaps try passing it _without_ `compact`, using just a plain array: `return view('index', ['name' => $name]);`.

Comment: Take a look here: [pass data to all views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040684/how-to-share-a-variable-across-all-views/35042335#35042335)

Comment: @camelCase still not working

Comment: And if you `dd($name)` in your controller, it is defined?

Comment: @koursaris not usefull for single view scope. I want to extend the scope of name variable to navbar view only

Comment: @camelcase it is defined. And working for index view

Comment: Then I'm not sure because it should be working. Perhaps you should show us the code you are using in `navbar` since the issue is with that file.

Comment: @camelcase i know that the scope of name variable is limited to the view it is passed to from laravel docs. That is what i need to do extend the scope of name variable to navbar view. But anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: No, it isn't limited. Read the section *Including sub-views* [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#control-structures), where it states: "Blade's @include directive, allows you to easily include a Blade view from within an existing view. All variables that are available to the *parent view* will be made available to the *included view*" which is what you are doing, right?

Comment: Yes . But see my case . I have the variable in a sub view of Parent view master. And i need that variable of sub view index in other subview navbar of parent master view.

Comment: Here, see [this image](http://imgur.com/7h1jgF8) of your case, working on my local machine. Is this not identical to what you have above?

Comment: Yes this is similar to what i have done. But $name is not found in navbar view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use @section in index view and @yield in navbar view as

**index.blade.php**

```
@extends('master')
@section('content')
    <h2>{{$name}}</h2>
@endsection
@section('nav')
    <h1>{{$name}}</h1>
@endsection
```

**navbar.blade.php**

```
@yield(nav)
```

Comment: this is exactly as what i want to do.

Answer (score 3):

Pass the variable to *master.blade* then *navbar.blade*:

```
@extends('master', ['name' => $name]) //compact('name')
```

Then:

```
@include('navbar', ['name' => $name]) //compact('name')
```

Comment: @extends('master', ['name' => $name]) //compact('name')

Then:

@include('navbar', ['name' => $name]) //compact('name')

worked.

Comment: as i dont want to use View::share which will make it global

Answer (score 0):

You should use a view composer for this.

[View Composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers)

```
view()->composer('master', function ($view) {
  $u_array = $var;
  $name = $u_array->name;
  $view->with(compact(name));
});
```

With some more explanation on your specific issue I may be able to assist you in better alternatives.

Comment: I have passed name variable to index view from controller which i need in navbar view as name variable via blade template engine.