# Use variable across entire application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use `$user = Auth::user();` in almost every route and within almost every view. I have dozens of routes and dozens of views so constantly having to repeat `$user = Auth::user();` feels wrong.

Is there a way that I can just call `$user = Auth::user();` once and then have it available across the entire application, including within routes and views?

I'm using Laravel 5.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5 you can get get more info from this post

Comment: That's to pass it to all VIEWS, but not across the entire app.

Answer (score 3):

In your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

within the `boot` method, paste this code. This will make `$user` variable accessible in all your views

```
view()->share('user', auth()->user());
```

Or if you don't like helper functions then you can instead use facades

```
View::share('user', Auth::user());
```

and import it at the top

```
use View;
```

For your whole app access, you can make use of `config` global helper.

put this line of code in your `boot` method

```
config('user', auth()->user());
```

to access it any where, use this

```
config('user');
```

Comment: I would like to expand on this: Doing this allows you to use the `$user` variable throughout your entire application without any issues. If something happened and `Auth::user()` were no longer available, you'd have to go change ten/hundred/thousand(s) of lines of code to reflect that. Aliasing this and making it application wide allows you to only make that change in 1 place. This is a similar concept to the [repository pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx).

Comment: This only passes it to all VIEWS, but not the entire app (like routes).

Comment: @ZaynAli I tried to implement your answer, but it returns null for user. It seems like this only stores the Auth::user() value in the start which is null as user is not logged in.... Not sure about it though....