# Laravel 5.3 Get Array Value

Tags: php, laravel

I stuck at getting value from app\Helpers\Enums\DriverType.php.

Here's my code:

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers\Enums;

final class Gender {
const MALE = 0;
const FEMALE = 1;
public static function getList() {
    return [
        Gender::MALE,
        Gender::FEMALE,
    ];
}

public static function getArray() {
    $result = [];
    foreach (self::getList() as $arr) {
        $result[$arr] = self::getString($arr);
    }
    return $result;
}

public static function getString($val) {
    switch ($val) {
        case 0:
            return "Male";
        case 1:
            return "Female";
    }
}

}

?>
```

my question is how can I get the value from the array in my driver\create.blade.
I have tried.

here's my blade code:

```
{!! Form::model($obj, 
[ 'url' => $route,
'method' => $method,
'id' => 'driverCreate',
]) !!} 
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
<div class="form-group">
<strong>Gender:</strong>
{!! Form::select('gender', array('Male', 'Female'), null, array('class' =>     'form-control')) !!}
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" >Submit</button>
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

any code needed to figure out how this works?

Comment: Can you paste your blade file code. You can always call the method statically with in the your project.

Comment: @anwerjunaid there's the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple options to share variables to view files.

**First One:**
From Controller you can pass variable

```
$genders = App\Helpers\Enums\Gender::getArray();
return view('view_name', compact($genders));
```

In you blade file just use $genders

```
{!! Form::select('gender', $genders, null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

**Second**
Call the class directly like

```
{!! Form::select('gender',App\Helpers\Enums\Gender::getArray(); , null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
```

**Third and probably most useful**
You can share gender with all the views as you may require them later.
In you providers file( AppServiceProvider is recommended) add these  lines

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
    {
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        $genders = App\Helpers\Enums\Gender::getArray();
        View::share('genders', $genders);
    }

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

`$gender` variable will be available in all your views.

**Fourth** View Composer
Laravel recommends this procedure, i have not used it, you can read about it [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608795/3305978)

In the end you will get select value as 0 or 1 which are your options, you can get enum value by

```
 $gender = Input::get('gender');
 $genderEnum = App\Helpers\Enums\Gender::getArray()[$gender];
 // or write another method for.
```

Comment: thank you so much anwer, but why i cant use $genders , it said undi variable. but it works using call class directly.

Comment: These are function based inclusion of files, they are designed this way. You have to declare variables to make them accessible in views.

Comment: @why when i press submit, show nothing.
i have tried dd($request); inside the function save, it show all the data. 
but cant submit it to database.

Comment: To save data to database you need Models, have you done that?

Comment: Add your controller code, Laravel uses Eloquent ORM, you can read about all database related actions in documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent

Comment: thanks, i can save to database now, but my datatable keep processing and dont load my data, try to console it. it say Cannot read property 'style' of undefined. alot of eror hahahah
sorry to bother u

Comment: Break down your problem and search for each error one by one. You may need to start from some basic tutorials. All developers go though same phase when starting something new.

Comment: @anwerjunaid second option was good one. But the code can be lengthy because of namespace, you can reduce it by putting the gender class in aliases at config/app.php. By the way the you can call all the static functions of the class from any of your blade templates