# Laravel - share data between all views

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel 5.2 version, and I have tried to share data between all views, but for some reason I can't get it to work. In my `Controller.php` `__construct function` I have setup it up like this, but this is not working:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesResources;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, AuthorizesResources, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    public function __construct()
    {
        view()->share('user', Auth::user());
     }
}
```

I am trying to render that in my navigation partial like this:

```
<li>{{ $user->name }}</li>
```

Comment: If you're accessing the currently Authenticated user couldn't you just use `{{ Auth:user()->name }}` ?

Comment: no, nothing gets rendered then as well

Comment: I think you need to put `use Auth;` (or what works in your version. I use 5.3 and its `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;`) in your controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) or use [view composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers) for that.

Also, you don't need to create separate variable for `Auth::user()` or `auth()->user()`, because you already can use those in all views out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit 2:** For Security Reasons You can't get Auth in Controller.php, but you Can create CustomController.php that extents from Controller, and you other controllers must extends from CustomController, In Custom Controller you can use Auth, and Share $user with all views.

try this way and don't forget to use Auth;

```
View::share('user', Auth::user());
```

instead of your

```
view()->share('user', Auth::user());
```

And The [Article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5) that can help you

**EDIT:** I have tried it in my Laravel 5 App just type

```
 \View::share('user', Auth::user());
```

That's all.