# Laravel access data from all views

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

In all of my views I am already able to access `{{Auth::user()->name}}` by default, I am trying to add the ability to access `{{Profile::user()->...}}` in my views as well but I am having some trouble.  I don't really want to use view composers if I dont have to as [this post suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39876186/laravel-share-data-between-all-views) because it looks like I will need to list each view manually.  Instead I opted in to use the [AppServiceProvider boot method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) listed in the docs.  The problem is I am still not able to call `{{ Profile::user()->title }}` for example.  I am getting the following error:

```
ErrorException in AppServiceProvider.php line 19:
Non-static method App\Profile::user() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context
```

**Here is my AppServiceProvider.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use View;
use App\Profile;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
        View::share('user', Profile::user());
    }

    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

**Here is my model Profile.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'bio',
        'linkedin_url',
        'facebook_url',
        'twitter_username',
        'title',
        'profile_image',
        'user_id',
    ];
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }
}
```

***What am I doing wrong?  How can I have access to users profile data in all views?  Can I see an example?***

Comment: Do you want profile of logged-in user?

Comment: Does the User model have the relationship to Profile? You can then use {{ Auth::user()->profile->myAttribute }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to share this variable at all since you only want to get profile of user (you always have user data loaded) and it's one-to-one relation. Just add proper relation:

```
public function profile()
{
    return $this->hasOne('\App\Profile');
}
```

And then use it anywhere in the app:

```
auth()->user()->profile->city
```

If you'll share the variable, you'll add second query to all views and in the real app you absolutely don't want to do that.

Comment: This is the one that got me what I needed, thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Both @Saumya and @martindilling are correct; you're binding to the `$user` variable in the service provider you're using. You just need to make your `user()` method static to access it the way you want:

```
public static function user(){
    if (auth()->user()) return auth()->user()->profile;
}
```

If you use that, then you don't need the View binding if you don't want it. You can just use `{{ Profile::user() }}` in any Blade template. But this is also kind of silly, because now you've overwritten your relationship method name.

If you really want super-easy access to the current user's profile, why not make a helper method you could access from anywhere? `currentUserProfile()` or something? I don't mind keeping a file with some shortcut methods for each project, but you have to have good discipline when adding things to it otherwise your code will quickly become unreadable.

I find the second answer [here](http://laravel.io/forum/02-03-2015-best-practices-for-custom-helpers-on-laravel-5?page=1) to be a pretty clear way to add your own custom helper methods.

Comment: Also a good answer,I had everything else working with the relationship, I just did not know it was as simple as calling `auth()->user()->profile` in my view (not realizing it was attached to user and thinking I needed a composer view, helper function or service provider to accomplish this) but I learned from your answer as well so thank you

Answer (score 1):

According to your code, you are calling a non-static method statically. You shouldn't be doing that. Instead you should use a profile, for which you want a particular user like this:

```
View::share('user', Profile::find(1)->user);
```

You can also get all the users with profile like this & your models should look like this:

```
class User extends Model {

    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

}

class Profile extends Model {

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

}

View::share('user', User::with('profile')->get()); // <----- Get all users with profile
```

Or if you want to get the profile of the authenticated user, you can do it like this:

```
View::share('user', auth()->user); // <---- Gets the authenticated User
View::share('user_profile', auth()->user()->profile); // <---- Gets the authenticated User's profile
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: When I try using `View::share('user_profile', auth()->user->profile);` in the boot method I get the following error: `Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$user`

Comment: Thank you, now I get the following error: `Trying to get property of non-object` I assume it is the `profile` part of `View::share('user_profile', auth()->user()->profile);`  I made sure my profile model has user method and user model has profile method like your example above.

Comment: According to my code everything is fine, make sure that your `profile` table has the column `user_id` and the relationships are properly used & defined!

Answer (score 1):

When you use `View::share('user', Profile::user());` your profile user would be available in the view as `{{ $user }}` :)

And yes the error message you get is because of the reason Saumya Rastogi has written, that you need to get the user for a specific profile :)