# How do I make a logged in user object available to all views in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to be able to get a logged in user's details in my views. E.g `{{ $user->email }}`.

Here's my `Controller.php`:

```
public $view_data = array();

public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth');
    $this->view_data['user'] = Auth::user();
}
```

`$user` in my views return `NULL`. Am I missing something?

Comment: have a look into http://stackoverflow.com/a/28608795/1728836

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already available in all views by default via:

```
Auth::user()
auth()->user()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly access loggedIn user in your views via following methods:

```
{!! Auth::user()->name !!}
{!! auth()->user()->name !!}
{!! access()->user()->name !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

{{ \Auth::user() }} 
{{ \Auth::user()['email'] }}

Answer (score 0):

Laravel already provide this service after you logged in. Just simply write:

```
{{ Auth::user()->email }}
{{ auth()->user()->email }}
```

You can also use ServiceProvider for all views:

create service provider: `php artisan make:provider UserServiceProvider`

Go to

> app\providers\UserServiceProvider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Auth;

class UserServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function boot()
    { 
        if(Auth::check()){
            $user= Auth::user();
            View::share('user', $user);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

Than register this service provider inside the `config\app.php`

```
App\Providers\UserServiceProvider::class,
```

Now user object available for all view you just simply write:

```
{{ $user->email }} 
{{ $user->username }}
```

[Laravel Sharing Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#sharing-data-with-all-views)

Comment: He's talking about accessing it in the views in which case `auth()->user()->:field:` would suffice.