# Laravel 5.3: Routes in layout views

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, view

Having a problem with the links in the menus.

At the moment, the linkage between the views is done through links inside of views which are ruled by the controller.

Example, in this view,

[image: here]

we have the show view for companies.

The link that says 'Edit About Page Tiago', looks like the following:

```
<p><a href="{{route('company.companies.about.edit', $company->companyID)}}">Edit About Page {{$company->Company_Name}}</a></p>
```

where $company->companyID is being grabbend from the controller, which looks like this:

```
public function show($id)
    {
        //

        $company = Company::findOrFail($id);

        return view('company.companies.show', compact('company'));

    }
```

and has the following route:

```
GET|HEAD  | company/companies/{company} | company.companies.show | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyCompaniesController@show | web,company   

GET|HEAD  | company/companies/about/{about}/edit | company.companies.about.edit | App\Http\Controllers\CompanyAboutController@edit | web,company   |
```

At the moment, when I try to access, through the menu, 'About', I'm trying to access this:

```
        <li>
            <a href="{{route('company.companies.about.edit', $company->companyID)}}"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-fw"></i> About</a>
        </li>
```

which is code inside of a layout view. The following error comes through:

[image: here]

What can I do for, once pressing the 'About', to be redirected in the same way like in the 'Edit About Page Tiago'?

Asking it in another way, where can I give the information to $company if that variable is inside of a layout view and not in a normal view which I can do through the controller?

It might be a basic problem to solve, but somehow is blocking me.

**Any given help is appreciated**

Tiago

Comment: Try to dump the company variable in the controller (var_dump($name_of_variable))

Comment: What do you mean?

To which controller?

Because is a layout view. How is that done for this specific case?

Comment: You can refer to [Data With All Views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views) in the **Sharing Data With All Views** section ! hope that helps

Comment: it gives some orientation, let's see what one can do with that, thanks!

Comment: Please do *not* add `[solved]` to post titles. Questions do not need to be marked as such. If you have found your own solution, feel free to post that as an answer below, or if one of the answers was helpful in solving the problem for you, consider marking that answer as accepted. Otherwise, there is nothing you need to do. Remember that questions and answers are here for *future visitors*, and they'll make their own determination on what is helpful, or if they have found a solution, wether or not they'll post a new answer then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Maraboc said, you can [share data with all your views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#passing-data-to-views) in a service provider, but in order to do this you need to know/set the values ahead of time, during the bootstrapping process. This functionality is typically used for global values like base titles, meta tags, etc that you want to manage say in your database or through some sort of custom CMS.

There is another way to share variables across views using [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/views#view-composers) which may better fit your use case.

Comment: having a look at it atm, will let you know how it went. Looks like a good solution though

Comment: sorry haven't managed to make it work yet using this solution. Will try once again during the next 3 hours and let you know how it went.

Any help would be really awesome though.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I was using different method than default `route`.In my view,

```
<a href="editcompany?id={{$company->companyID}}" class="btn btn-xs btn-info" >EDIT </a>
```

in my `route.php` I have

```
Route::get('editcompany','CompanyController@edit');
```

In my Controller, edit function looks like this

```
public function edit()
{

    $id = Input::get('id');
    $company = Company::find($id);
    return view ('your view',compact('company'));
}
```

Comment: Found this link, which might have some great info. Trying to take some 'juice' out of it.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5





At the moment, though about:

1- create a provider with artisan
2- use the company info in the boot() method.


Why this wouldn't work: we would be trying to fetch database records before they exist (lorey Oct 4 '15 at 21:41) (it has 6 upvotes)