# get loggedIn user in View Composer not working(Sentinel - Laravel 5.4)

Tags: php, laravel, global-variables, laravel-5.4, sentinel

I am using Sentinel in Laravel 5.4. What I am trying to do is: **get logged user detail but `Sentinel::getUser()` returns null**. For this process, I have seen this instruction in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608795/4807414)
 . I am following using `View Composer` method.

**Steps I have done**

I have created a file `ViewComposerServiceProvider` inside `Providers` folder. It looks like:

```
public function boot()
    {
        $user      = Sentinel::getUser(); //<<-- main error: dd($user) returns empty
       $userDetail = UsersDetail::where('user_id', $user->id)->firstOrFail();

       if ( is_null ($userDetail) ) {
           $userDetail = new UsersDetail;
       }

       view()->composer('backend.*', function($view) {
           $view->with('userDetail', $userDetail);
           //$view->with('userDetail', 'Test'); //this works fine
       });
    }
```

Then, I register this provider in `config/app.php` Providers array as 
`App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class,`

When, I pass other variables in `userDetail`, it's working perfectly. But, I cannot get the logged in user detail. Am I missing something?

Following the first solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28608795/4807414) also seems not working since, construct are run prior to the Middleware. Any help please.

Comment: please replace firstorFail to first();

Comment: Another option check can you get $user->id

Comment: Please check it.

Comment: I have mentioned in question, `$user` is null.

Comment: please see documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views

Comment: Something change view()->composer to  View::composer(

Answer (score 0):

Go to `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` 
Then your serviceProvider.php boot method like below

```
public function boot()
{

 $user      = Sentinel::getUser(); //<<-- main error: dd($user) returns empty
       $userDetail = UsersDetail::where('user_id', $user->id)->firstOrFail();

       if ( is_null ($userDetail) ) {
           $userDetail = new UsersDetail;
       }

    View::composer('userDetail', function($view) use($userDetail ) {
    $view->with('userDetail ',$userDetail );
    });
}
```

Then your userDetail.blade.php you can access userDetail data like this

```
{{ $userDetail }}
```

Comment: Its not problem with the `$userDetail` variable passed to blades, problem is `Sentinel::getUser()` is responding null.

Comment: please replace firstorFail to first()