# How to use global variables in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, global-variables

Is it possible to share and change some variable between multiple views? For example, I want to have a variable $user that will be shared between all views. When a user logs the variable is set up, when the user logs out, the variable is unset. I was unable to achieve requested using 
the following combination:
in AppServiceProvider:

```
view()->share('var', 1);
```

in the controller:

```
$var = view()->shared('var');.
$var ++;
view()->share('var', var);
return view(''', 'var'=>$var)
```

Every time when the page is reloaded $var is always the same (2).

Comment: [Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28608527/2815635)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to have a variable $user that will be shared between all views

You should use `auth()->user()` to get authenticated user instance in any view.

But if you don't want to use it for some reason, you could share the variable between multiple views with a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers).

`share()` method will be useful only if you want to share a variable with all views. To make it work, put `view()->share('key', 'value')` to the `boot()` method of a service provider.

Also, the code in your controller looks like you want to share data not between views, but between requests. Use [session](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/session) for that.

To save the data:

```
session(['key' => 'value']);
```

To get the data in another request:

```
session('key');
```

Comment: But why does my code doesn't behave as expected?
Why isn't shared var incremented for 1 each time?

Comment: @ЂорђеЖивановић you need to put `view()->share('key', 'value')` to the `boot()` method of a service provider and then use it in any view with `{{ $key }}`

Comment: As I stated in my comment:

in AppServiceProvider:

view()->share('var', 1);
But I need to change that variable when a user logs in.

Comment: @ЂорђеЖивановић it looks like you want to share the data between requests, use session for that. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to add another service provider. Take a look at my provider:

```
  <?php

     namespace App\Providers;

     use Request;
     use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;


 class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
public function boot()
{

   $this->globalThings();
   //call another globals' function here
}

public function register()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Get the golbals
 */
private function globalThings()
{
    view()->composer(array('*.*'),function($view){
        //get the data however you want it!
        $view->with('global', Model::where('field','value')->get());
    });
}
```

And don't forget to add the service provider to list of provider is config/app.php

```
        App\Providers\ViewComposerServiceProvider::class,
```

Comment: Is there a way to call this provider just once, when my server starts?Because I am trying to mock up a database in this way.