# Laravel 5: PHP variable shared by all methods of controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a resource controller. The route for that is like this-

```
Route::resource('branches/{branch_id}/employees', 'EmployeeController');
```

The problem is in every method I need to pass the branch variable to the view.

```
public function index($branch_id){
    $branch = Branch::find($branch_id);
    $employees = Employee::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    return view('employees.index', compact('branch', 'employees'));
}
```

Is there any way that I can pass the branch variable to each view returned through this controller?

@Sapnesh Naik Its not a duplicate as I need to manipulate the branch in each function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data to all views in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5)

Comment: if you need to pass the variable to specific view then https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/views#view-composers, otherwise use `view::share`.

Comment: @SapneshNaik Actually I'm do not totally agree, he's looking to manipulate the `branch_id` in the `controller` not in the `view`

Comment: @SapneshNaik It sounds like you only read the title of this question. The one you linked is not a duplicate.

Comment: @SebastienD and Emile exactly...

Comment: @EmilePels He specifically asked "Is there any way that I can pass the branch variable to each view returned through this controller" That obviously means that he needs to pass a variable to each of the view in a controller. Route model binding and using `find()` yeild the same result. So your answer does not answer the intent he expressed in the title as well as at the end of the question

Comment: @SapneshNaik Its not a duplicate as I need to manipulate the branch in each function, Its not a constant.

Comment: Do you need to pass the variable to every view or just `employees.index`?

Comment: @TheAlpha Every view that is being returned from this controller.

Comment: @SapneshNaik For just a second, think of what problem he is trying to solve - which is that he does not want to have to explicitly fetch the `Branch` model in every handler. Route model binding solves this problem, and the question you linked does not let him do that in a clean way.

Comment: @EmilePels In the comments he mentions he wants the variable to be passed to "Every view that is being returned from this controller." vpalade s answer achieves that

Comment: @SapneshNaik Yes, and he also needs the Branch model to be available in each of the controller's handler. This is obviously his intent, although he may have worded it a bit odd.

Comment: Thanks @SunnyKumar for fixing the mistake in my answer and for the thumbs up, +1 :-)

Comment: @TheAlpha and Thank you for solving my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you may try this:

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    view()->share(
        'branch', Branch::find($request->route('branch_id'))
    );
}
```

You may also use `request()->route('branch_id')` if you don't use method injection by type hinting the `Request $request` in your `__construct` method.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your controller constructor:

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        view()->share('branch', Route::current()->getParameter('brach_id'););
    }
```

Comment: The `$request->get('branch_id')` will return `null` because `branch_id ` is not a request input instead it's a route parameter.

Comment: Still the answer is wrong, check my corrected answer.