# Laravel - Share data with all views when the data is available

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization, laravel-views

I'm writing a web app using Laravel 5.6. I need a list of all the connections the current session user have, in all the views.
I tried something like this

```
View::share('connections', Connection::getList(Auth::id()))
```

I put this code inside the boot function of AppServiceProvider. But the problem arises when the user isn't already logged in, because at that time `Auth::id()` is set to null.

The connection list is not generated when the user logs in. This throws the following error:

> connections variable is not defined.

Comment: Why don't you check `Auth::id()` first, and if it's `null`, initialise `connections` to a default value?

Comment: @fubar no, the problem is that the boot function is only being called once. So, connection list is not generated at log in. I've also tried moving this function inside the login controller.

Comment: Ah, I see. It needs to go somewhere that is called on every request. I typically put such code in a parent controller. Have you considered using a [ViewComposer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#view-composers)?

Comment: ^View composer is what you want

Comment: @fubar how do I use parent controller for this?

Comment: @SuperKevin I've tried with composer as well, the problem persists.

Comment: You extend all of your applications controllers by a given parent controller. And in the parent constructor, you call `View::share()`. And if a `ViewComposer` isn't working, you're likely doing something wrong. Post the code how you were using it, and we can try to help.

Answer (score 2):

This target can achieve through different method,

**1. Using BaseController**

The way I like to set things up, I make a `BaseController` class that extends Laravel’s own `Controller`, and set up various global things there. All other controllers then extend from `BaseController` rather than Laravel’s Controller.

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    //its just a dummy data object.
    $user = User::all();

    // Sharing is caring
    View::share('user', $user);
  }
}
```

**2. Using Filter**

If you know for a fact that you want something set up for views on every request throughout the entire application, you can also do it via a filter that runs before the request — this is how I deal with the User object in Laravel.

```
App::before(function($request)
{
  // Set up global user object for views
  View::share('user', User::all());
});
```

**OR**

You can define your own filter

```
Route::filter('user-filter', function() {
    View::share('user', User::all());
});
```

and call it through simple filter calling.

**Update According to Version 5.***

**3. Using View Composer**

View Composer also help to bind specific data to view in different ways. You can directly bind variable to specific view or to all views. For Example you can create your own directory to store your view composer file according to requirement. and these view composer file through Service provide interact with view.

View composer method can use different way, First example can look alike:

You could create an `App\Http\ViewComposers` directory.

*Service Provider*

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        view()->composer("ViewName","App\Http\ViewComposers\TestViewComposer");
    }
}
```

After that, add this provider to config/app.php under "providers" section.

*TestViewComposer*

```
namespace App\Http\ViewComposers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;

class TestViewComposer {

    public function compose(View $view) {
        $view->with('ViewComposerTestVariable', "Calling with View Composer Provider");
    }
}
```

ViewName.blade.php

```
Here you are... {{$ViewComposerTestVariable}}
```

This method could help for only specific View. But if you want trigger ViewComposer to all views, we have to apply this single change to ServiceProvider.

```
namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
class ViewComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {
    public function boot() {
        view()->composer('*',"App\Http\ViewComposers\TestViewComposer");
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5)