# Laravel 5.6 pass variable to view from middleware

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a way to pass a variable to the view with middleware?
I was able to do this using a session, but this didn't resolve my problem, so I'm asking for this.

Comment: What is your requirement?

Comment: Do you want share any common value in all view?

Comment: Not all, just some of them.

Comment: no way! you cannot even return view from middleware.

Comment: So you can use session if possible

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish actually? Mingling request middleware with a view is the worst thing you can do. Don't mix responsibilities.

Answer (score 4):

Middleware is used to modify the request.

If you have some dynamical data that you use for each view then its best to use a service provider and not middleware.

For example, you may have on each page some meta data and each view includes a `header.blade.php` which may look like this:

```
<head> <meta name="{{$meta_key}}" content="{{$meta_desc}}"> </head>
```

Then you could create a [service provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/providers)

```
 public function boot()
 {
    view()->composer('view', function () {
        $slug = request()->path();

        $meta = \MetaTags::where('slug' ,'=',$slug)->first();

        $view->with('metatag', $meta->tag);
    });
 }
```

You may also check this tutorial from [laracast](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25)

Comment: I'd like to add dynamic data which need to request database and memcached to all views, should I use middleware or service provider?

Comment: @shintaroid service provider.

Comment: Thanks bro!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5
by the way, in the left question there are answers suggest using middleware (if I'm not misunderstanding the question), do you think middleware is also a solution?

Answer (score 1):

Replace 'view' in composer by path where to you want send data

i.e. if you want to send to header.blade.php which is in partials folder,then replace 'view' as 'partials.header' .

After referring [@adam answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56626122/5803974)  and [Laracasts episode 25](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/25) following code work for me:

**\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php**

Add following codes in **boot() function** :-

```
 view()->composer('partials.header', function ($view) {
            //

            $view->with('your_key', 'your_value');
        });
```

Now your data is available at **project_name\resources\views\partials\header.blade.php** as

```
{{$your_key}}
```

or

```
<?php echo $your_key; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following code, you can easily access the data in the view:

```
view()->share('my_variable', $variable);
```

Now you can use `{{$my_variable}}` in your views.

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the variable into the request, read it from the request on the controller, and then pass that on to the view.

For example, in the middleware:

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $foo = 'bar';
    $request->merge(compact('foo'));

    return $next($request);
}
```

On the controller:

```
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $foo = $request->foo;
    return view('my.view', compact('foo'));
}
```

Then on the view, you can reference it as, e.g. `{{ $foo }}`.