# Laravel sharing data with all views

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, controller

I'm trying to run a user-related query to fetch data to appear in the top bar of my site on every view.

I've created a new BaseController according to the first answer here:

[How to pass data to all views in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5)

and that's working for a simple test (just sharing a typed-out variable), but when I try and use `Auth::user()->id` in the `__construct` method of BaseController (which in my other controllers always returns the ID of the currently logged in user), I get `Trying to get property 'id' of non-object`.

I've tried adding `use App\User` at the top of BaseController (even though it isn't usually needed) and also tried adding in the bits for Spatie laravel-permission plugin, but neither has any effect.

I tried dd on `Auth::user()` and just get 'null'. My feeling is that the user details maybe haven't been loaded at this stage, but BaseController extends Controller same as MyWorkingController extends Controller so I'm not sure why `Auth::user()->id` doesn't work here when it does normally?

Comment: You should use [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#sharing-data-with-all-views). `auth()->user()` won't be available in your constructor since it is trying to fetch this from session which is not available in constructors.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Base Controller which has all the information that you want to share too all controllers/pages/views and let your others controllers extend it.

Comment: If you re-read my question, that is exactly what I'm doing and what the linked answer suggests. The problem is that the information I want to share doesn't seem to be available to the BaseController.

Comment: I just saw it. Try to do it not in the __construct and see if it works. __construct is loaded before all other things and it's possible to be because of that.

Comment: Problem is though, I need the function to run automatically for every page load. Is that possible if I put the code in some other function I create?

Comment: I think somewhere I used a code just like Abdullah Al Shakib commented here in the last comment.

Answer (score 0):

open file AppServiceProvider.php from folder Providers  and write below code in boot function

```
     view()->composer('*', function ($view)
    {
        $view->with('cartItem', $cart );

    });
```

And now go to your view page and write :

```
{{ $cartItem }}
```

Comment: $view->with('cartItem', $cart ); in this line $cart will be replaced by your data which you want to share to all your view

Comment: This worked for a simple typed-in variable but I still couldn't use `Auth::user()->id` to get the current user ID. I added `use Auth` and `use DB` so I could run my query to get the information but then got a big error about Symfony framework stuff

Comment: you can use everything just check my second answer

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access `Auth` in constructors because `middleware` has not been run yet. You can use either [View composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/views#view-composers) or give try this way though i haven't tested.

```
class BaseController extends Controller {
    protected $userId;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
           $this->userId= Auth::user()->id;

           return $next($request);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Presumably then I'd just use `$userId` instead of `Auth::user()->id`? I tried doing it but got undefined variable error

Answer (score 0):

Write this in AppServiceProvider.php

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use DB;
use Auth;
use App\Cart;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

            view()->composer('*', function ($view)
            {

                view()->composer('*', function($view)
                {
                    if (Auth::check()) {
                        $cart = Cart::where('user_id', Auth::user()->user_id)->count();
                        $view->with('cartItem', $cart );
                    }else {
                        $view->with('cartItem', 0);
                    }
                });


            });

    }


}
```

In you view simply write

```
{{ $cartItem }}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work but I did have to edit it because I don't have cart, and maybe my replacement is what broke it. Do you have a non-cart example, something that all Laravel installs contain?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested, I just encountered the same problem and I've solved it with `ServiceProvider`:

1. Define your custom `ServiceProvider` with the command

```
php artisan make:provider CustomServiceProvider
```

2. Add a reference to your service provider in the `config\app.php` file, specifically in the `providers` array, adding this item to it:

```
\App\Providers\CustomServiceProvider::class,
```

3. Declare the variables you want to share in your provider's `boot()` method and share them by using the `view()->share` method:

```
public function boot()
{
    $shared_variable = "Hello";

    view()->share('shared_variable', $shared_variable); 
}
```

4. You can now reference your variable in your blade files with the standard notation:

```
{{ $shared_variable }}
```