# How can i pass Category::all(); to every view

Tags: laravel

I will use the category a lot of places in my views to show, is there a way to insert somewhere so that I can use it in every view without getting this error Undefined variable: categories

At the moment i am doing it like this for every view:

```
$categories=Category::all();
 return view('posts.create',compact('categories'));
$categories=Category::all();
 return view('posts.edit',compact('categories'));
```

and so on..

Comment: This is a step-by-step doc for view::share https://scotch.io/tutorials/sharing-data-between-views-using-laravel-view-composers

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data to all views in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this in the constructor of your base controller

```
$categories=Category::all();
View::share('categories', $categories);
```

Here is more info in the laravel docs

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/views#sharing-data-with-all-views

Answer (score 1):

You need `AppServiceProvider` to do that on `app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php` :

```
public function boot()
{
  $categories=Category::all();
  $view->with('categories', $categories);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@bumperbox's solution is good!

An alternative is to add a view composer with the wildcard * in your AppServiceProvider.

```
View::composer(['*'], function ($view) {
    return $view->with([
        'categories' => Category::all(),
    ]);
    
});
```