# Laravel 10 access cookie data in all views

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

To add a shoppingcart which is viewable from all pages on my laravel webpage I created a service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cookie;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\View;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ViewServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //

    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        //
        $cart = json_decode(Cookie::get('cart'), true) ?? ["abcs"];
        View::share('cartItemsCookie', $cart);
    }
}
```

However the value of $cart is always ["abcs"], because for some reason the (Cookie::get('cart') is empty.

However in different views when I add in the controller for example:

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $cartItems = json_decode($request->cookie('cart'), true) ?? [];
    return view('cart.index', compact('cartItems'));
}
```

Than the expected values for cart are visible.

How can I share cookie data with all views?

Comment: You could create custom middleware to retrieve the cookie data and share it with all your views.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data to all views in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608527/how-to-pass-data-to-all-views-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @OMiShah no that does not tell why my solution is not working.

Comment: can you try: ``request()->cookie('cart')`` instead of ``Cookie::get('cart')``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try custom middleware.

```
class ShareCartData
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $cart = json_decode($request->cookie('cart'), true) ?? [];
        View::share('cartItemsCookie', $cart);

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Register the middleware in the `app/Http/Kernel.php` file within the `$middlewareGroups` array:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        // ...
        \App\Http\Middleware\ShareCartData::class,
    ],
    // ...
];
```

Then, you could access the `cartItemsCookie` variable in all your views.